# compression algorithm for non-repeating integers

Tags: algorithms, compression

I have an array of unique integers, for example: {1,3,,7,9,31,46,...}, which I want to compress. I have found compression techniques and algorithms for the list of integers, where some integers are repeated but I couldn't find any compression technique for list of unique integers. I would appreciate if anyone could help me to get an idea so that I could start with.

I have 1024 datasets of size 512 where where each value is a distinct integer between 1 and N (or 0 and N-1), i.e., a permutation of a set of N consecutive integers. I also assume that there is given a tolerance x and so, I want to find a compressed representation that allows the original values to be recovered with deviations no greater than x.
Thanks.

Comment: Are the values of the array _always_ increasing?

Comment: No, they are not always increasing. They are something like, for example:  [320 314 311 312 316 317 318 319 315 321 322 313 402 404 324 
  406 407 307 308 309 405 304 305 323 403 408 306 310 398 400 401 
  409 302 294 303 399 411 285 296 299 325 397 286 295 298 301 410 ]; stored in a text file.

Comment: They are "stored in a text file". The first thing that comes to my mind, of course is zip compression. You surely tried that and dismissed it for some reason. Can you explain on that?

Comment: If n ints each has a possible range of size r, there are r^n possibilities. If they are additionally distinct, there are rPn possibilities. The former requires n log(r) bits of storage; the latter log(rPn) bits, which is roughly n log(r) for n << r. Therefore the distinctness will not save you much. Possibly not even 1 bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to consider that *compression* - by which I assume you mean *lossless compression* - equates to the removal of **redundant information**. If you write 12,12,12,12,12 there's redundance and you can write it as 12*5.

So you need to find the information that you can make redundant. For example the sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,19,20,21 is nonrepeating, yet there is redundance and you can "compress" it as 1,7,18,4 (storing the first element of an increasing sequence and the number of elements) or 1,7,18,21 (storing the first and last elements of all sequences).

Then you must keep in mind that this kind of compression a *trade* - instead of using a set of symbols with some known occurrence probability you use another set, with a different spectrum, organized so that the *most likely sequences* map to the *shortest symbols*, even if on average the symbols are bulkier. **But there will always be a killer sequence** to which your compression will be applied with little result, or even catastrophic results (as *whatsitsname* remarked, most random sequences will turn out to become *larger*; which is why applying a compression unsuited for **your** data will likely avail little). For example in the "1,2,3..." sequence, if you get 1,3,5,7,9,11,13 you're forced to store it as 1,1,3,1,5,1,7,1,9,1,13,1 -- *doubling* the sequence size. For the same reason if you rename a .zip file as .dat (to prevent Zip from refusing to compress it) and try to compress it, you'll notice that once compressed, the file actually gets *larger*. Perhaps by very little, perhaps just by that handful of bits necessary to store the information "This file is stored uncompressed!" - but larger nonetheless.

Finally you need to state what you *mean* by *compression*. Are you referring to the number of integers in the sequence? Or the number of characters in its text representation? Say you have 1,7,9,5,11. You notice that no number is larger or equal to 12. So no product of any two numbers A and B will be larger than 11*A+B (actually a product of N<sub>0</sub>, N<sub>1</sub>, ...N<sub>n</sub> can be translated as 11<sup>n</sup>*N<sub>n</sub>+...+11<sup>0</sup>*N<sub>0</sub>). Using Horner's algorithm, *n* integers become *one* (larger) integer. Using a larger base for clarity (100 instead of 12), 1,7,9,11 becomes 1070911. In characters, you haven't gained that much - eleven characters have become seven (using 12 as base, 1-7-9-11 becomes 2855 which is *four* characters). Counting integers, four have become one - or rather two, as you need to account for the need of storing the 12 also.

If you have an increasing sequence, you can store the first number and the differences (1-3-7-9-31-46 becomes 1-2-4-2-22-15), which may yield smaller numbers, which might be useful, though they'll now be probably non-monotonic.

Finally, a sequence with *no* redundancy because there is *no* relation between the previous numbers and the next one, so that each number provides 100% information on itself - in other words, a random sequence - will never be losslessly compressible, because there is nothing to squeeze out. You will be able to compress its textual representation, but this is not what your question seems to suggest.

So, without more information on the sequence's characteristics and your specific scenario, I'm afraid there's very little that can be done for you.

## Case in point

You need to deal with VERY large numbers (N=512, and you don't want to manipulate (N-1)! without heavy duty gloves).

But the main problem is that the permutation is essentially random, so compressing the numbers is not going to work reliably; I think we might have better luck with some ad hoc coding.

Now every integer in itself holds 9 bits of information (512 = 2<sup>9</sup>), so your data set is at a first glance actuality composed of 4608 bits (or 4599, since the last number is uniquely identified by the other 511 - it's the only one missing from the set).

But this is assuming that it's not a permutation but a combination, that every integer is free to assume any value; we do not exploit the uniqueness constraint, which adds at least 511 bits more information, or in other words requires 2<sup>n</sup>*(n-1)+1 bytes, not 2<sup>n</sup> * n. Let's look at it more closely.

The first number (0) has 512 possible positions which we can code in 9 bits (2<sup>9</sup> = 512).

The next number can only go in one of the remaining 511 positions, which still requires 9 bits. In short, the first 256 numbers all need 9 bits.

When the number of positions remaining drop below 256, we can use 8 bits. So, the next 128 numbers can be coded into the remaining 256 positions using 8 bits, until the number of free positions becomes 127.

And so on, until the 511th number can only go in either of two positions and requires one bit.

One number is left and it can only go in the last place, so it adds no information and it makes for a further 0 bits.

So we need

```
256*9 + 128*8 + 64*7 + 32*6 + 16*5 + 8*4 + 4*3 + 2*2 + 1*1 bits =

= 2304 + 1024 + 448 + 192 + 80 + 32 + 12 + 4 + 1 =

= 4097 bits
```

which is 2<sup>n</sup> * (n-1)+1 (in this case it looks like 2<sup>14</sup>+1).

You can represent those 4097 bits using 133 dword integers from 0 to 2147483648 if you want to code them in the smallest possible number of *integers*.

If you want to code them in the smallest possible number of *decimal digits*, then you want to find a power of ten which is the nearest possible to the immediately lesser power of two. With a number of bits below 32, this happens with three: 2<sup>3</sup> is 8, which requires one digit, and in one decimal digit you can code at the most the number 9.

But taking into account the *separator*, a single digit requires *two* characters each three bits, if you also need the comma (you mightn't, because one digit needs no separator).

The best becomes then 2<sup>23</sup> or 8388608, seven digits (plus one comma, eight).

So your 512 numbers (1940 characters) become (4097/23) * 8 = 1432 numeric characters and commas. Or it is an uninterrupted sequence of (4097/3) * 1 = 1366 digits. Using 63 bits and numbers up to 2<sup>63</sup>-1 or 9223372036854775807, we get around (4097/63)(19+1) = 1300 characters.

At best, you can code the sequence into 683 base64 characters, or a 65% reduction, which makes your 1024 dataset 684 Kb in total.

(Or you can binary-code it into 513 bytes).

## The algorithm

```
Let BUFFER be your sequence of numbers (137, 410, 128, ...)
initialize a vector POSITION[512]
for i = 0 to 511 included:
    # The position of number BUFFER[i] (e.g. 128) is 2.
    POSITION[BUFFER[i]] = i

next = 256
for i = 0 to 510 included:
    POS = POSITION[i]
    # How many unchecked positions are between 0 and POS?
    Q   = 0
    for j = 0 to POS:
        if COPYOFBUFFER[j] >= 0:
            Q = Q + 1
    # Mark the POS-th address as "checked" by setting it to -1
    COPYOFBUFFER[POS] = -1;
    # Or you could set it to the first unused number, 512, as MAXVAL, and
    # modify the previous cycle  to check that COPYOFBUFFER[j] < MAXVAL

    # Now, i-th number is uniquely identified by Q
    # And Q is uniquely identified by a diminishing number of bits
    output(Q, bits)
    if (i == next):
        bits = bits - 1
        next = next / 2
```

The function "output" will output 8 bits (one character) or maybe 6 bits (one Base64 digit) and keep the rest internally, prepending said rest to the next call. You will need to make a last call to flush any remaining bits.

This is a not too efficient C implementation.

```
/**
 * outputs N bits (maximum N depends on integer type)
 * @param n   number of bits
 * @param val value holding the bits in its "n" least significant bits
 */
void output_bits(int n, int val) {
    static int buffer = 0;
    static int bits   = 0;
    if (0 == n) {
        // The request to output 0 bits makes no sense and is used
        // to mean "flush the buffer".
        // If the buffer contains 5 bits, we need 3 additional bits.
        if (0 == bits) {
            // buffer is already flushed.
            return;
        }
        n    = 8 - bits;
        val  = 0;
    }
    int mask = 1 << n; // we have 000111 (so, 7) and 3 bits. We get 0100 (4)
    while (n--) {
        // shift buffer by 1 bit left to accommodate next bit.
        buffer = buffer <<= 1;
        if (val & mask) {
            // We have a 1.
            buffer |= 1;
        }
        bits++;
        if (0 == (bits % 8)) {
            // We have a full byte.
            output_byte(buffer & 0xff);
        }
        // Shift the mask right to get the next bit.
        mask >>= 1;
    }
}
```

To reconstruct the array, proceed in reverse: as soon as you've gathered enough bits to retrieve a Q, move into the buffer by Q empty positions and place the number there:

```
 |__________________________________________|
 read first byte:  23, but we need 9 bits
 read second byte: 139, so the first number is 23*2+(139/128) = 47
      and the remainder is (139-27) = 112
 read first Q: 47
 ...so the first number, 1, goes into slot 47
 |______________________1___________________|
 now read third byte: 34, so the second number is 112*2+(34/128) = 224
 the second number, 2, should go into the 224th empty slot, which is
 number 225 because slot 47 is already taken
 |______________________1__________________2____|
 ...and so on.
```

## Another algorithm

You can squeeze some more bits out of the sequence by operating as follows. You code the position of the first number among the 512 still free spaces in the sequence using 9 bits. Then, the second number's position requires a number from 0 to 511 to identify the p-*th* free slot in the sequence. 511 is 8.99718... bits. You have now need of coding *fractional bits*, and you can google those and look e.g. [phase-in codes](https://hbfs.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/phase-in-codes/).

The sequence will now size [image: sum] which is rounded to 3867, from the original naive estimate of 4599, or a reduction of around 16% to 484 bytes. Decoding will be quite slow as you need to walk the whole sequence to translate a number to its true position.

Comment: "But there will always be a killer sequence" - more specifically, **most** inputs will result in a longer output.

Comment: @whatsisname,  I don't think you're taking this full answer into account: that the OP would need to find and factor out redundancy that occurs in the typical situation for the domain of interest.  The OP -- as far as i can tell -- is not asking how to compress random (generally uncompressable) data. So this answer, that says to find some pattern due to properties of domain, has merit.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I'm not saying the answer doesn't have merit, I'm elaborating on a principle referenced, to further drive the point that the properties of the domain is of critical importance.

Comment: @whatsisname, I completely agree. I incorporated your comment, because one consequence is that getting "some compression method" and applying it blindly will in all likelihood return unsatisfactory results.

Comment: @whatsisname, thanks, that's helpful clarification!

Comment: @LSerni: Good explanation!  The answer to your question about more information on the sequence's characteristics is that I have 1024 datasets of size 512 where where each value is a distinct integer between 1 and N (or 0 and  N-1), i.e., a permutation of a set of N consecutive integers. I also assume that there is given a tolerance x and so, I want to find a compressed representation that allows the original values to be recovered with deviations no greater than x.

Comment: This is probably more suited to Stack Overflow, but I'll try and add to the answer.

Comment: @Angela you need to update your original post with that information...

Comment: @LSerni: so, Do I need to sort the list first before converting the given integers to binary form? Sorry, I am getting confusion here after trying to convert the given integers in the dataset into bits.

Comment: No, you keep the list as it is (otherwise all permutations would collapse into the natural numbers sequence - OEIS A000027). I've added a sample algorithm, but haven't reviewed it too carefully - I sometime switch 0-indexes and 1-indexes. Try first with a very short permutation of the first 16 numbers (requiring 4 bits initially), with pencil and paper.

Comment: @LSerni: I have two doubts here- one is that, is it necessary to take COPYOFBUFFER array instead of the original BUFFER array? Other question is how can I code the integers between 256-512 using less than 9 bits if they are in the not in the first 256 positions in the original array? I am trying to implement your algorithm step by step in c and I  appreciate your help to start with as I really want to develop my understanding for this problem.

Comment: @Angela, that is because I was unclear in the description of the algorithm and left out the "punching" of the buffer slots. This happens in a copy of the buffer in order not to lose data. As for the bit output, I've tried to provide some code I hope is working. You need to call the output_bit function at the end with n=0, val=whatever to ensure that all bits are indeed flushed.

Comment: @LSerni: Here I have a question, which I would appreciate if you could have any pointer on is that,  why we need unchecked positions between 0 and pos in the code ? One more thing, I didn't get is, what would be stored in array POSITION[0]  if the integers are given in range 1-N?

Comment: As for the position, I'm used to work in the range 0..N-1; when you said, 512 integers, I numbered them 0 to 511. If you have them numbered 1-512, you need to modify the code adding "-1" wherever appropriate. The punched/unpunched positions between 0 and 511 are used to map  positions to the smallest needed number. E.g. if 300 slots are already taken (you're coding the 301st number), its position need not be represented by a number between 0 and 511 (as was the 1st), but between 0 and 211. And *that* will only need 8 bits, not 9. (if necessary you may ping me on my obvious gmail account).

Comment: @LSerni: I may need your assistance regarding the output as you really helped me to understand the problem and to get optimal solution. so, could you please let me know how I can reach you via gmail account?

Answer (score 4):

## **Edit:**

According to you, you are actually doing this:

> I have 1024 datasets of size 512 where where each value is a distinct integer between 1 and N (or 0 and N-1), i.e., a permutation of a set of N consecutive integers. I also assume that there is given a tolerance x and so, I want to find a compressed representation that allows the original values to be recovered with deviations no greater than x.

So the question really is "How do I compress permutations of a set of numbers", in this case *you only care about order* as you know the set of numbers before hand.  In this case, you can store each value as 9bits, and you've encoded the location of that value, for 512, this will be 4608 bits, or 576 bytes.  You can't go any futher than this *unless you have additional information about the ordering of said numbers*, as you are trying to compress *random information*.

But, if you aren't doing this *truly randomly* you can store each permutation, or even the entire set of permutation *in a single seed*.  In all seed spawned pseudo random number generators, if you use the same seed you get the *exact* same result.  If this is your case you can store your entire data set in potentially 4 to 8 bytes (depending on the algorithm, you may need larger seed values), no matter the size of your data!

If you need to load the data back, you just use the same seed again!

## Delta encoding

This is the same idea as this [answer here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/360091/267185), but with a different implementation:

If, like the cited user stated, your data doesn't change that much, but your min and max values over your entire sequence is quite large (and you have a lot of numbers) you can use delta (differential) encoding.

You can use the mean, min, max or some starting offset value if the above conditions apply (I'll use min)

In your example,

> [320, 314, 311, 312, 316, 317, 318, 319, 315, 321, 322, 313, 402, 404, 324, 406, 407, 307, 308, 309, 405, 304, 305, 323, 403, 408, 306, 310, 398, 400, 401, 409, 302, 294, 303, 399, 411, 285, 296, 299, 325, 397, 286, 295, 298, 301, 410]

The min value is 285, and the max value is 411.  Since your max value is over 256, you are potentially storing up to 16 bits (though you can lower this to 9 if you know 411 is your absolute max)

The difference between those two values is 126, so you can actually store the differences as 7 bits for each number.

There are 47 elements, and with 9 bits per element, if you know the max is less than 512, you end up with 423 bits needing to be stored

With naive delta encoding, you would first encode the first value (9 bits potentially) then encode the differences from that value in the rest, for example, 9 bits, + 7 * 46 = 331 bits for this sequence.

You don't have to do this over your entire sequence, you can do this over several number long segments as well, with the same pattern, but also including the length of the sequence (if it cannot be fixed length), with additional sequence segments min values being in terms of the previous min value (differentials in thier own right) or every value sitting with in a max capture range (ie 8bits if max value is 255, 9 if 511, 16 if 2^16 -1 etc..)

A better solution may be If you know the absolute difference between each element will not exceed a maximum value, you can use that as your differential instead, unfortunately for the given dataset, the outcome would be the same (410 - 301, consecutive numbers, is 109, which still requires 7 bits to encode), but would reduce overhead on consecutive sequence (as you would be storing the difference from the last number, not a set starting point).

If you didn't need information in order, you could further compress this information *by converting the sequence to a sequence with the smallest differential between each consecutive number*.  This would take longer to compute initially (you would need to sort the numbers), and you would lose order, but you would still be able to tell the individual numbers in the set itself, and how many duplicates there are for each number.  This would solve the issue I showed earlier with using consecutive deltas encoding, as you can see with the sorted sequence

> [285, 286, 294, 295, 296, 298, 299, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411]

The largest delta value now is 294 - 286, 8, which can be stored in 4 bits instead of 7, but because you state

> where some integers are repeated but I couldn't find any compression technique for list of ***unique*** integers

we can guarantee that no two elements are the same, and encode this sequence as *3bits* per element, and use the 000 as 1 instead of zero (since we can't get a 0 difference)

so now you just need 285, (9 bits), and the rest of the delta encoding (4bits). So now you have 9 + 4 * 46 = 193 bits, with 3bits its 9 + 3 * 46 = 147, a full 288% smaller than the original sequence minimal encoding at 423 bits (though technically not lossless as we lose ordering).

this could be useful if you only need the existence, frequency, total number, min and max, or usage of a number, and this could be applied to the entire dataset no matter how large and wouldn't  need to be segmented, or we could use the previous segmentation techniques if we encoded length and differential size for each segment.

The more specific you can be about what exactly you need, the better compression we can get as well (as you can see with the unordered delta encoding)

Answer (score 2):

If the integers are large, but the difference between successive values is usually small, you can encode the difference between them.

For example, if you were tracking the the Dow Jones average as 2 byte ints, on most days you could use a signed byte to track the change.  The tricky part is that once in a while you can't, so you need one "escape" value, say -128, to indicate that you are handling this special situation, e.g. following with 2 bytes with the real value.

So most days will require 1 byte, but big swing days require 3.  With luck you can compress to roughly half the space.

Interestingly, if you follow this process with a standard "gzip" like compression, you often get great compression, cause there are patterns in the deltas.  Usually applying two different compression algorithms doesn't provide much savings.

Answer (score 1):

Little to be gained with using the "non-repeating" property of the data.  Simply use general compression techniques.

---

For discussion, assume there are 2<sup>n</sup> possible different possible integers and the array to compress if size `SZ`.

---

The first array element is one of 2<sup>n</sup>.  The next element is one of 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, then 2<sup>n</sup> - 2 and so on.

If 2<sup>n</sup> is much greater than `SZ`, this does not provide much reduction in information and so little benefit over general compression.

If `SZ` approaches 2<sup>n</sup>, (it cannot exceed and still have unique elements), then code could form a table of all ready encountered elements.  Once 2<sup>n-1</sup> elements have been encountered, then rather than trying to compress data that is `n` bits wide, code only needs to compress `n-1` bit wide information (using the index of a table of available values).  Repeat this process for the next `n/4` elements, then compress `n-2` bit wide information.  And so on.

To implement this, code could use a 2<sup>n-1</sup> table of values.

I'd expect no more that a reduction to (n-1)/n in compression size for a lot of work.

---

"I couldn't find any compression technique for list of unique integers." hints that a call for this compression of "unique" arrays has limited application and value over general compression.